# AngularJS - uncheck previous checkboxes when new checkbox is checked

Tags: angularjs, forms, input, checkbox, radio-button

Well, the question's pretty self-explanatory.

The thing is, this is an already developed project and, for reasons beyond my understanding, they want a radio button functionality for certain checkboxes. Why? Can't explain it and also can't change it.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this: basically you have handle the click of checkbox and mark others as not selected, you can achieve this by playing with the model value here.

sample:

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.chkList = [{
    name: "Ram",
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    name: "Shyam",
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    name: "Alice",
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    name: "Adam",
    isSelected: false
  }];

  $scope.deSelectOther = function(item) {
    $scope.chkList.forEach(function(listItem) {
      if (listItem.name != item.name)
        listItem.isSelected = false;
    })
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in chkList">
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deSelectOther(item)" ng-model="item.isSelected" />
 </li>
```

[plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7X5OHIfwWXGfGu29MFcL?p=info)

if no? post some of your code or further elaborate your requirement so that I can help you